# How to specify the image location based on left and top values

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in which i have one image and I need to specify the location in image.But i have left and top values of image only. But we need x,y,width and height values.Then how to find out values from these.So please tell me how to do that.

Comment: please provide further information on what you are trying to do here with example code

Comment: I have one image like map.In that i need to place pin in in place of that image.I have that location information as left and top values.But we need 4 values (x,y,width,height) to specify any location.

Comment: width and height values will be the dimensions of that pin image.

Comment: you can use centre property in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The left and top values are the x - y positions. The amount of space your image needs to cover the view (frame size) is the width and height. For example, if your image has to cover the full screen of iPhone, you should specify the frame as:

```
    image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
```

Comment: Ok.I used the that values for x and y like as u said.But that specify different location.

Comment: what are the values that you have, and what is the size of the other image, in pixels?